# Is there a function that returns an integer between a min and a max value?

Tags: dart

I'm pretty sure there is a function like this, I just don't know how to search for it properly.

Before using a lot of words I show you what I mean in an example:

```
// the function should have the following input:
getValueBetweenMinAndMax(int min, int max, int input);

// and the following output:
getValueBetweenMinAndMax(100, 200, 50) // should return 100
getValueBetweenMinAndMax(100, 200, 150) // should return 150
getValueBetweenMinAndMax(100, 200, 250) // should return 200
```

I just wanted to be sure, that there is no function like that before coding one on my own.
Thanks in advance guys !

Comment: What does the third argument (value) do? What is it for? I'm not sure I've understood completely the question

Comment: This is the input .. I want to input an integer and want to be sure that the returned value is at least min and at most max

Comment: I understand now. I don't recall having seen a pre-made function for that. Do you need help creating your own implementation?

Comment: I just found it. You can call .clamp(int lowerLimit, int upperLimit) on types of num :)
Thanks for trying to help me ! :)

Comment: Nice. +1 for the self-answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found it.
The method I searched for was .clamp(num lowerLimit, num upperLimit)

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/num/clamp.html

Answer (score 0):

it's a simple function with 2 if/then statements. you just have to write it yourself.

Comment: I know that, but I knew from other languages that they have such functions.
I just found it btw. It is .clamp(num lowerLimit, num upperLimit). But still thank you ! :)